# Get current selected string from autoit combobox

Tags: combobox, autoit

```
   #include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
   #Include <GuiComboBox.au3>
   #include <GuiComboBoxEx.au3>
   ; Create GUI
   $hGUI = GUICreate("Test", 500, 500)

   Global $hCombo = GUICtrlCreateCombo("", 10, 10, 250, 20)
   GUICtrlSetData($hCombo, "Atchu | Muthu | Ponreegan | Vijay | Vasu", "Vasu")

   $hGetButton = GUICtrlCreateButton("Get", 270, 10, 30, 20)

   Global $temp = " "

While 1

    Switch GUIGetMsg()
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
           Exit
        Case $hAddButton
           $temp = _GUICtrlComboBoxEx_GetEditText($hCombo)
           MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "You chose: " & $temp)
           Exit
    EndSwitch

WEnd
```

There are few names added to combo box, on clicking "Get button", it is not returning string. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not even run. There are two issues:

The first is that you use $hGetButton when creating the button, but $hAddButton when waiting for a GUI message in your loop. This is what causes your code to fail to run.

The second issue is that you are using the wrong function to read the combobox data. You should use GUICtrlRead

Fixing these issues makes the code work:

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
   #Include <GuiComboBox.au3>
   #include <GuiComboBoxEx.au3>
   ; Create GUI
   $hGUI = GUICreate("Test", 500, 500)

   Global $hCombo = GUICtrlCreateCombo("", 10, 10, 250, 20)
   GUICtrlSetData($hCombo, "Atchu | Muthu | Ponreegan | Vijay | Vasu", "Vasu")

   $hGetButton = GUICtrlCreateButton("Get", 270, 10, 30, 20)

   Global $temp = " "
    GUISetState ( @SW_SHOW , $hGUI )
While 1

    Switch GUIGetMsg()
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
           Exit
        Case $hGetButton
           $temp = GUICtrlRead($hCombo)
           MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "You chose: " & $temp)
           Exit
    EndSwitch

WEnd
```